# Preventing loading of packages removed from Emacs's initialization file

Tags: init-file, list-packages

Several packages continue to be available for use, even though I have removed them from `init.el` and restarted Emacs. However, this does not occur with `emacs -Q`. Previously, the persisting packages were installed using `use-package`. What could be the reason, and how to prevent this from happening?

**Shell:**

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 28.2
$ readlink -f ~/.emacs
/home/erwann/.emacs.d/init.el
$ cat init.el
;; init.el --- Emacs init file
;;
(provide 'init)
;;; init.el ends here
```

**Snapshots**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is analogous to this one:

> "I wrote a shell script which installs firefox, and I ran it, and firefox was installed.  I then edited my shell script and removed the line which installs firefox and I ran the script again, and to my surprise firefox is still installed on my system.  Why is that?"

(Or perhaps: "...and to my surprise if I type 'fire' and then TAB in my shell, it provides 'firefox' as a completion.")

The answer in any case is: It's still installed because you haven't uninstalled it.  *Not installing* something which is *already installed* has no effect on that thing.

Your init file is not a declaration of your whole Emacs config; it is a software program which is executed as *a part* of your config.  Your installed packages are another part of your config, and they are functional with or without an init file.

You can use the <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-packages` menu to manage your installed packages, or use the <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-delete` command directly.  Provided the package being deleted is not a dependency for something which is still installed, if will be removed.

I believe you'll want to read through <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Package Installation` -- that gives you all the information about managing packages, and controlling how they get activated, but note that:

- By default `package-initialize` initialises *all* of your installed packages.  This will only `load` the autoloads file for each package, though -- if they are being loaded any more than that, something has requested it.
- Emacs calls `package-initialize` before evaluating your init file (since 27.1). You can use `early-init.el` to tell it differently.
- You can use `package-enable-at-startup` to prevent Emacs activating *any* packages.
- you can use `package-load-list` to control which packages should be activated.

Comment: The problem is about packages that were removed from `init.el`, but appear to be loaded. I shouldn't have to delete them from installed packages to prevent them from loading.

Comment: `package-initialize` is not invoked. As shown, `init.el` is empty.

Comment: @phils: Maybe mention something about `package-initialize` in your answer, e.g., what you say in your comment.

Comment: I've updated the answer to incorporate my comments.